# PromQL default behaviour when no time range was given

Tags: prometheus, promql

When I was querying a Prometheus server with quite high scrape intervals, I stumbled across a behaviour I wasn't expecting: If I was omitting a time range, metrics weren't continuous, which could best be seen from the *Graph* window:

[image]

My assumption was, that if I queried for `up{job="prometheus"}`, it would simply return the *latest* metric scraped, independent of *when* this has been. But this just doesn't seem to be the case - especially as all scrapes have been successful to this target.

As I haven't found a good explanation, can you please tell me what the *actual* outcome is, if I just queried for a metric without a time range like the one in the example above?

[Edit]

Even places like the [Promlabs Cheat Sheet](https://promlabs.com/promql-cheat-sheet/) say

[image]

Answer (score 1):

See [valyala's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73588018/11934850) to "Why is the moving average higher than the actual series in prometheus".

The query from Grafana to Prometheus includes some step parameter, so in fact you'll always get discrete points. Prometheus then delivers the latest value at each of these step points with a maximum look-behind of 5 minutes.